# Creating a CSV file header dynamically in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark

We receive 2 files (data file and metadata file) from Vendors for data ingestion.

```
Vendor 1 
data file format
user_id has_insurance postal_code city
101        Y        20001       Newyork
102        N        40001       Boston
metadata file format
user_id,String
has_insurance,Boolean
postal_code,String
city, String
```

we will receive same data fields from another vendor but fields order in data file might be different as below

```
Vendor 2
data file format
user_id  postal_code   city     has_insurance
101        20001       Newyork  Y
102        40001       Boston   N
metadata file format
user_id,String
postal_code,String
city, String
has_insurance,Boolean
```

The metadata file will contain the fields order. Is it possible to assign schema dynamically based on the metadata file while reading CSV file?

//function to derive spark datatype for the given field data type

```
def strToDataType(str: String): DataType = {
     | if (str == "String") StringType
     | else if (str == "Boolean") BooleanType
     | else StringType
     | }

val metadataDf = spark.sqlContext.textFile("metadata_folder")
val headerSchema = StructType(metadataDf.map(_.split(",")).map(x => StructField(x(0),strToDataType(x(1)),true)))

 val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .schema(headerSchema) // defining based on the custom schema
    .load("data_file.csv") 


val headerSchema = 
StructType(bxfd.map(_.split(",")).map(x => StructField(x(0),strToDataType(x(1)),true)))
```

when I tried to create schema dynamically using the above command, getting below error. Could you please advise.

```
<console>:34: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the CSV data source in this case, but you can parse it yourself without too much difficult.  The basic steps are read the metadata file as one text blob, then the data file separating data lines from header lines and apply the schema.

I made some assumptions about your separators. One thing to remember is you shouldn't assume any ordering to the lines in your DataFrame once you load it, because you don't know what data is being loaded on what worker.  This tries to identify data vs metadata lines based upon their content, so you may need to adjust those rules.

```scala
def loadVendor(dataPath: String, metaPath: String): DataFrame = {
    val df = spark.read.text(path)

    // First read the metadata file, wholeTextFiles lets us get it all
    // as a single string we so we can parse locally
    val metaText = sc.wholeTextFiles(metaPath).first._2
    val metaLines = metaText.
        split("\n").
        map(_.split(","))

    // Identify header as line that has all the field names
    val fields = Seq("user_id", "has_insurance", "postal_code", "city")
    val headerDf = fields.foldLeft(df)((df2, fname) => df2.filter($"value".contains(fname)))
    val headerLine = headerDf.first.getString(0)
    val header = headerLine.split(" ")

    // Identify data rows as ones that aren't special lines or the header
    var data = df.
        filter($"value" =!= headerLine).
        filter(!$"value".startsWith("Vendor 1")).
        filter(!$"value".startsWith("data file format"))

    // Split the data fields on separator and assign column names. Assumed any whitespace is your separator
    val rows = data.select(split($"value", raw"\W+") as "fields")

    val named = header.zipWithIndex.map( { case (f, idx) => $"fields".getItem(idx).alias(f)} )
    val table = rows.select(named:_*)

    // Cast to the right types
    val castCols = metaLines.map { case Array(cname, ctype) => col(cname).cast(ctype) }
    val typed = table.select(castCols:_*)

    // Return the columns sorted by name, so union'ing multiple DF's will line up
    typed.select(table.columns.sorted.map(col):_*)
}
```

Here is the data printed

```
scala> df.show
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+
|   city|has_insurance|postal_code|user_id|
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+
|Newyork|         true|      20001|    101|
| Boston|        false|      40001|    102|
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

And here is the schema printed

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- has_insurance: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
```